# Jupyter is not finding sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Python3 in Spyder and in a Jupyter notebook. When I try to load sklearn in  the console of Spyder, for example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

It works fine. But if I do the  same thing in Jupyter, it tells me that I don't have this module installed:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-daefd108d0e6> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried to reinstall with condas and pip3 and they tell me that sklearn is already installed... ¬¬

I have found similar questions in Stackoverflow, but none of them could find an answer. I would be very grateful for any help. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance your python and Jupiter use different python versions, can you provide the following output:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

for both Jupiter and Spyder

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer!!!! Spyder says: 

3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4]

And Jupyter says:

3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4]

So, both the same, right?

Comment: Thanks for keep helping me! The answer to both (I have done it in both and compare the results in Meld Diff Viewer) is: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/dist-python']

Comment: So just to be clear both of them gave the same result?

Comment: Yes. They give the same result when I do site.getsitepackages(). Spyder: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/dist-python'] Jupyter: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/dist-python']

Comment: Ok, I think we are finding the problem. When I do import sklearn; sklearn.__file__ the response is: '/home/jose/sklearn/__init__.py'. Jupyter doesn't have access to this path, right? Thank you so much for the help!!!!

Comment: So do I have to add this path to jupyter? How exactly? Why does Jupyter has no access to this?

Comment: how did you install sklearn? can you just pip install sklern?

Comment: Hi. I don't remember how I installed sklearn. I normally install everything with pip3, so I guess I did that. If I give sudo pip3 install sklearn, the console responses: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sklearn)

Comment: Hi again. So, I uninstalled and installed sklearn again witht pip3. And it didn't fix the problem. So I did import sys; 
import os; sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/jose/")); and then I can finally load sklearn in Jupyter. This is not THE solution, but it is the best solution that I can currently find. The most annoying thing is that I have to append this path to the sys everytime I open a new notebook... Any improvement from that would be great. Many thanks to @etlsh !!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
```

and remove the folder

```
kernels
```

It seems that a series of installs/uninstalls causes this problem.